# Write out the contrapositive to the statement

Tags: logic

Statement:           $(\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \rightarrow (\lnot p \vee \lnot q)$

contrapositive:      $(p \wedge q) \rightarrow (p \vee q)$

This is also a tautology

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Can't think of anything else to say.